# Populating list using constructor method

Tags: python, csv, oop, constructor, init

I am trying to use the constructor method to populate a list of cities in Python using data from a .csv. However, I'm not understanding how to automate the process. I can instantiate cities one at a time, as shown below, but have over 30 rows and would really prefer to not do this by hand. Below is a sample of the code I'm using, and [how the data is stored in Python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbcES.jpg).

```
##Step 1. Open and read CityPop.csv
file = "CityPop.csv"
try:
    csv = open(file, 'r')
##Step 1A. Deal with bad inputs
except:
    print("Could not open" + file)
    sys.exit()


##Step 3. Create "Cities" list
Cities = []

##Step 2. Create "City" class
class City:
    ##Step 4. Use __init__ method to assign attribute values
    def __init__(self, lat, lon, name, yr1970): 
        self.lat = lat
        self.lon = lon
        self.name = name
        self.yr1970 = yr1970


city_1=City(35.6832085, 139.8089447, 'Tokyo', 23.3)
city_2=City(28.6082802, 77.2008133, 'New Delhi', 3.53)

Cities.append(city_1)
Cities.append(city_2)
```

Is there a more efficient way that I can accomplish this? Thanks!

Comment: Pass the file handle to an actual csv reader (via `import csv`), and build up your instances with a list comprehension.

Comment: Why don't you want to use the solution from the answer you got [yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55214011/7414759)?